# Set view pager id to display group of view pagers

Tags: android, android-viewpager

App gives casting error when try to set id to view pager programatically.
If do not set id programatically, then able to see only 1st view pager contents.
How to create view pagers programatically which can display view pagers one below other?
I am trying to add view pager to linear layout of xml. As soon as I use setId for view pager, it crashes.
It does not even go to onCreateView of fragments. Which TextView is it referring to then?

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.configureTransitionsOrdered(FragmentTransition.java:314)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:138)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1862)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1820)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1695)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:299)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:256)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1244)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1308)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:350)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:724)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2422)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1504)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1761)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1392)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6752)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

MainActivity

```
 private fun createviewpagers(listOfQuestionnaire: List<Questionnaire>) {
        for (i in 0 until listOfQuestionnaire.size) {
            var viewPager = ViewPager(context)
            viewPager.id = View.generateViewId()
            viewpagerAdapter= ProgramQuestionAnswerActivityAdapter(supportFragmentManager,listOfQuestionnaire.get(i))
            viewPager.setClipToPadding(false)
            viewPager.setPadding(70, 0, 70, 0)
            viewPager.setPageMargin(40)
           viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(8)
            viewgroupmain.addView(viewPager)
            viewPager.adapter= viewpagerAdapter;

        }
    }
```

ProgramQuestionAnswerActivityAdapter

```
public class ProgramQuestionAnswerActivityAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
int mCurrentPosition;
Questionnaire activitiesList;

    public ProgramQuestionAnswerActivityAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Questionnaire activities) {
        super(fm);
        activitiesList = activities;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
            return activitiesList.getQuestions().getData().size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        QuestionnaireQuestions questionanswer = activitiesList.getQuestions().getData().get(position);
        mCurrentPosition = position;
        return ProgramQuestionAnswerFragment.newInstance(activitiesList.getName(),questionanswer, position, activitiesList.getQuestions().getData().size());
    }
}
```

ProgramQuestionAnswerFragment

```
public class ProgramQuestionAnswerFragment extends Fragment implements TimePickerDialogViewInterface {
    @BindView(R.id.viewgroup)
    LinearLayout mainparentviewgroup;
    @BindView(R.id.textCurrentQuestionnumber)
    TextView textCurrentQuestionnumber;
    @BindView(R.id.ivnext)
    ImageView tvnext;
    @BindView(R.id.ivback)
    ImageView tvback;

    Context context;
    QuestionnaireQuestions acttivities;
    private int pos, size;
    private String name;
    private Unbinder unbinder;
    List<QuestionnaireAnswer> selectedanswer = new ArrayList<>();
    private Integer timeclicked = 0;
    TextView txtTime;
    private SimpleDateFormat displayableTimeFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());

    public static ProgramQuestionAnswerFragment newInstance(String name, QuestionnaireQuestions activities, int position, int activitiesListsize) {
        ProgramQuestionAnswerFragment f = new ProgramQuestionAnswerFragment();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putSerializable("activities", new Gson().toJson(activities));
        b.putInt("pos", position);
        b.putString("name", name);
        b.putInt("size", activitiesListsize);
        f.setArguments(b);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context _context) {
        super.onAttach(_context);
        if (_context instanceof Activity) {
            context = _context;
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.e(" on create ", "view");
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.programme_questionnaire_group, container, false);

        acttivities = new Gson().fromJson(getArguments().getString("activities"), QuestionnaireQuestions.class);
        pos = getArguments().getInt("pos");
        size = getArguments().getInt("size");
        name =  getArguments().getString("name");

        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        mainparentviewgroup.setTag(0);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        if (acttivities != null) {
            if (acttivities.getQuestionTypeId()==( SINGLE_ANSWER_QUESTION_TYPE_ID)) {
                createFreeTextQuestionAnswer(acttivities);
            } 
        }
    }


private void createFreeTextQuestionAnswer(QuestionnaireQuestions activities) {
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = vi.inflate(R.layout.programme_question_free_text_layout, mainparentviewgroup, false);

    TextView txtTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvtitle);
    TextView txtBody = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvbody);

    txtTitle.setText(name);
    txtBody.setText(activities.getQuestion());
    mainparentviewgroup.addView(itemView);
}
```

R.layout.programme_questionnaire_group

```
version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/rel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/text"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp">

        <!--YOUR CONTENT-->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/viewgroup"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            </LinearLayout>


            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relnex"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/viewgroup"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:paddingTop="14dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textCurrentQuestionnumber"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textColor="@color/lightGreyText"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <!--<TextView-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/tvnext"-->
                <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:layout_alignParentRight="true"-->
                <!--android:layout_marginTop="5dp"-->
                <!--android:layout_marginRight="22dp"-->
                <!--android:drawableRight="@drawable/right_arrow"-->
                <!--android:drawableTint="@color/black"-->
                <!--android:drawablePadding="2dp"-->
                <!--android:fontFamily="sans-serif"-->
                <!--android:letterSpacing="0.0"-->
                <!--android:text="NEXT"-->
                <!--android:textColor="#3a98e4"-->
                <!--android:textSize="13sp"-->
                <!--android:textStyle="bold"-->
                <!--android:visibility="gone" />-->

            </RelativeLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivnext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/right_arrow"
                android:tint="@color/black"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivback"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/left_arrow"
                android:tint="@color/black"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

programme_question_free_text_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvtitle"
        style="@style/smallBoldText"
        android:text="my leep "
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvbody"
        style="@style/smallText"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="my leep " />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etfreeanswer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:hint="Type here..."
        android:gravity="top"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_greysolid_border"
        android:minHeight="108dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```